# CakePHP Unit Test Common Custom Assert

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This is probably a really easy one, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have written some custom assert functions for unit testing my models. I would like these functions to be available in all of my unit tests, no matter the model. Where would I put these so that they are available to every unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MyCakeTestCase which extends the CakeTestCase. 
There I can put all my custom methods.

see this test for example:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Test/Case/Lib/CaptchaLibTest.php

just put your own test case in your lib folder (either app or - as I prefer - plugin):

```
/app/Lib/
/app/Plugin/PluginName/Lib/
```

and either lib or pluginlib uses statement:

```
App::uses('MyCakeTestCase', 'Lib');
App::uses('MyCakeTestCase', 'PluginName.Lib');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me?

Added this to the to of my Unit Test file :

`App::uses('CustomAssert', 'Lib');`

The file is in my Lib folder, but I cannot access any of the functions inside the class?

Comment: why not? how do you access them? I thought you wanted to extend the CakeTestCase? Seems you are just including the lib class.

Comment: Not sure I must be doing it wrong some where along the line. Here is what I have done.  
  
1) Moved all of my custom assert methods in to a new class called CustomAssert which extends CakeTestCase. This is saved in a file called CustomAssert.php which lives include /app/Lib/  
  
2) In my UnitTest file I have included `App::uses('CustomAssert', 'Lib');` 
  
3) I had assume that I would be able to access these tests through $this-> however I cannot.  
  
I am probably not initialising something somewhere? I am not sure.

Comment: you need to use this case then SomeTest extends CustomAssert. i strongly suggest you name it PrefixCakeTestCase, though. Just look at my code examples. Its all there right in front of you. I promise: it works if you do it like that.

Comment: Ah ha, I have it now! My UnitTests weren't extending MyCakeTestCase I was still just extending CakeTestCase! Thanks for your help.